# Firestore Query Not Returning Documents on the End Date in AngularFirestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using AngularFirestore (Angular's official Firestore library) to retrieve documents from a collection named 'A'. The documents have a 'created_at' field of type timestamp. My goal is to fetch all the documents that fall within a specific date range defined by a date range time picker. To achieve this, I'm using the following Firestore query in my Angular application:

```js
get(dateStart, dateEnd) {
  let docsA = this.fstore.collection<A>('A',
    x => x.where("created_at", ">=", dateStart)
          .where("created_at", "<=", dateEnd)
          .orderBy("created_at", "desc")).get();

  return docsA;
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the query returns all the documents in the collection from the 'dateStart' to 'dateEnd', excluding the documents that were created exactly on the 'dateEnd'. For example, if my Firestore collection has the following documents:

```json
{created_at : 19 July 2023 at 10:13:55 UTC+1}
{created_at : 20 July 2023 at 10:13:55 UTC+1}
{created_at : 25 July 2023 at 10:13:55 UTC+1}
```

And if I want to retrieve all documents between the dates 'Jul 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)' and 'Jul 25 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)', the query only returns documents 1 and 2, while excluding document 3 which was created on 'Jul 25 2023'.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions to correctly fetch all documents that fall within the specified date range, including the ones on the 'dateEnd'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Jul 25 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 is before Jul 25 2023 10:13:55 GMT+0100. (You can check that on this [website](https://www.epochconverter.com/))

So for the third document `created_at <= dateEnd` is `false`.

If you want to include "all the times" from 25 July you need to either use Jul 25 2023 23:59:59 GMT+0100 or Jul 26 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100.